# Can I set metadata attributes on my Image such as, Title, Comment, Rating, Tags in Android?

Tags: android, metadata, exif

I am using the ExifInterface and was looking at the documentation but can't see how I would set these values in android. Is it possible?

To clarify, I am explicitly looking for how to set values mentioned in the question

[ExifInterface Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this [setAttribute(String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) ?

For example :

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);

String tag = exifInterface.getAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION,0); 

exifInterface.setAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION, "90");
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

Comment: I understand how to use the ExifInterface method. But the question was whether I could set attributes such as Title etc.. (not mentioned in the ExifInterface documentation) could I just use string values from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534418%28VS.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534418%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @user1 did you see any tags of you want in `ExifInterface`? I guess not.

Comment: No I didnt see any tags in `EifInterface` that I needed to use.. Where there's a will there's a way

Comment: Actually thinking about this.. Of course `ExifInterface` wouldn't allow you to set title, comment etc... it only interacts with `Exif` information defined [here](http://www.slrphotographyguide.com/exif-metadata.shtml)